# Conditionally adding a semi-colon to a string

Tags: c

I have a very simple task that I am having a hard time with: I would like to add a `;` to an expression if it's not found in the string. For example:

```
"a+b;"  --> "a+b;"   // don't need to do anything
"a+b+c" --> "a+b+c;" // add a semi-colon
```

Here is the code I have so far, but it seems very odd, in that on only some of the cases do I do a `malloc`, but I'm not sure if there's a way around that:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage is $ script \'expression\'.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char *_input_string;

    // If the input expression does not contain a ';', add it to the end.
    if (!strchr(argv[1], ';')) {
        char *str = argv[1];
        size_t len = strlen(str);
        _input_string = malloc(len + 1 + 1);
        strcpy(_input_string, str);
        _input_string[len] = ';';
        _input_string[len + 1] = '\0';
    } else {
        _input_string = argv[1];
    }

    // now re-write the string as constant, because we don't want it to change
    const char* const input_string = _input_string;
    printf("%s\n", input_string);
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a better way to do the above pattern? I was hoping that I could add it to an array of length `strlen(argv[1]) + 2` but it seems that VLAs weren't allowing me to do that.

For example, if I try and do:

```
char xstr = argv[strlen(argv[1]+1+1)];
```

> main.c:15:21: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
> char xstr = argv[strlen(argv[1]+1+1)];

Comment: OT, but regarding the comment "now re-write the string as constant" that doesn't really do what the comment states. The memory that both `_input_string` and `input_string` is pointing to (it's the same memory after all) can be modified, only not through the `input_string` pointer directly (but the `const` part can be casted away and the memory modified without any compiler or run-time problems).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks -- what does "OT" stand for?

Comment: `char xstr = argv[strlen(argv[1]+1+1)];` --> `char xstr[strlen(argv[1])+1+1];` to be a valid VLA

Comment: Also, take care when doing the assignment `_input_string = argv[1]`, because after that the pointer can't be passed to `free`. Which you should do if you have allocated the memory with `malloc`.

Comment: "OT" is an abbreviation of "Off Topic".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude how would you suggest doing the `const` otherwise then?

Comment: For the `free` issue I would personally use `strdup` (or make my own if your system doesn't have it) to always have a heap-allocated string. Then you don't need any special case or checking when you `free` the memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sensible solution is to always malloc 1 byte more than necessary<sup>1)</sup>. That is:

```
size_t length = strlen(argv[1]);
char* str = malloc(length + 1 + 1); // room for ';' + room for '\0'
```

Then always copy the whole string. (You shouldn't be write-accessing `argv` strings if it can be avoided, even though those technically are read-write.)

```
strcpy(str, argv[1]);
```

This gives you are string ending with `\0` and then after that one allocated byte extra containing garbage.

Then check if the last character before the null terminator is semicolon. If not, add one at the end of the string, where the null terminator currently sits. Then write a new null terminator to the extra byte allocated:

```
if(str[length-1] != ';')
{
  str[length]=';';
  str[length+1] = '\0';
}
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> It is often senseless to write code that does a lot of effort finding out the exact amount of memory used and then allocate accordingly. Saving one byte here and there on the heap doesn't matter the slightest on modern computers. Extra malloc calls or `if` statement branches do matter a lot though, since they introduce performance bottlenecks. Thus:

Bad code, includes an unnecessary check + branch:

```
if(str[length-1] == ';')
{
  str = malloc(length + 1);
}
else
{
  str = malloc(length + 1 + 1);
}
```

Good code:

```
str = malloc(length + 1 + 1);
```

Comment: There's misc error handling necessary for a real application, I left it out on purpose. For example you should be sanitizing argv to see if it actually contains a null terminator within a sensible max amount of characters, to prevent buffer overflows when you do `strcpy`.

Comment: `str[length-1] != ';'` it is not good code. What about `"test;    "`?

Comment: @0___________ If that's a valid use-case, then that's another story. The OP didn't mention such, however.

Comment: I rather advocate function use in the answers.